# jQuery(this) : how to toggle the next table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, this

I would like to show/hide the table of the following structure when the user clicks on the link :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
        <h2>$header</h2>
    </div>
    <p class="howto">balbalblablablalbalbalbalblabla <a href='#'>link</a></p>
        <table id=table_action class="widefat">
        ...
        </table>
</div>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, and i don't understand why :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('.howto a').click(function() {
        jQuery.(this).next('table').toggle();
    });
});
```

For me :
jQuery.(this) refersto the dom element on which the event has been triggered, and there is a table element, what's wrong with my snippet ?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link `$('.howto a')` sits inside `.howto`. Calling `.next()` on the link returns nothingness.

Instead, try this inside the `.click()`:

```
jQuery(this).parent().next('table').toggle();
```

**EDIT**

Also, you might want to add a `.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior from happening when clicking the link:

```
jQuery('.howto a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parent().next('table').toggle();
});
```

Comment: ok, this works. thanks for your explanation. need to go out of the class 'howto' using parent to fetch the next table. thanks so much, Greetings ben

Comment: If you could mark my answer as accepted I would be most delighted :)

Answer (score 2):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kNjdU/1/)

Code:

```
 jQuery(this).parent().next('table').toggle();
```

You had two issues in your code:

1. `jQuery.(this)` instead of `jQuery(this)`
2. Calling `.next('table')` on the anchor element but the table is next to the parent paragraph element. Calling `.parent()` before `.next` resolves this.